# FANN install problems using PEAR on windows? PEAR Version: 1.9.4 , PHP Version: 5.4.12

Tags: php, pear, fann

I am trying to install FANN (Fast artificial Neural Network) on window using PEAR. But I keep getting following error.

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12>pear install fann

No releases available for package "pear.php.net/fann" - package pecl/fann can be
 installed with "pecl install fann"
install failed
```

I also cleard cache & updated channels using commands

- pear clear-cahe
- updat-channels

Then also I am getting same error.

I have following versions

PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.4.12

Then Finally I tried to install using pecl. it didnt work.

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12>pecl install fann

downloading fann-1.0.5.tgz ...
Starting to download fann-1.0.5.tgz (36,948 bytes)
..........done: 36,948 bytes

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 285

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\pear\System.php on li
ne 285
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\tmp\fann
```

I Dont know whats wrong.

Comment: why not just follow the error messages? Delete the file C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\tmp\ and see what happens

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka: I did this and I got following error   C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12>pecl install fann
downloading fann-1.0.5.tgz ...
Starting to download fann-1.0.5.tgz (36,948 bytes)
..........done: 36,948 bytes
5 source files, building
WARNING: php_bin C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.exe appears to have a suffix \php
5.4.12\php.exe, but config variable php_suffix does not match
ERROR: The DSP fann.dsp does not exist.

Comment: In cases like that, either I re-install it all. Or, I download the source file of the extension you want, and build it myself....Do yourself a favor, you rather do LAMP and not WAMP if you are in the compiling business.